# Participle Clause - Adjectival or Adverbial

Tags: participles, adverbials, adjectivals

It is hard for me to parse the participle clause in the following sentence and to know whether it is an adjectival or adverbial clause.

> "Notices were placed in the press all over the United States, asking
> people to contact the filmmaker if they knew how to get hold of
> trained ravens."

I think the participle clause **asking people to contact the filmmaker** is an adverbial clause of result and I can rewrite the total sentence as:

> Notices were placed in the press all over the United States, *so that
> people could contact the filmmaker* if they knew how to get hold of
> trained ravens.

Is my understanding right?

Or, is it in any way an adjectival clause?

Comment: The most usual would be: "Notices were placed in the press all over the United States and asked people to contact the filmmaker if they knew how to get hold of trained ravens."

Comment: It's a good question, actually; I'm not sure. Let's look at some simpler sentences. "He skipped down the street, whistling a tune." The -ing clause is adverbial. "I received a letter asking for funds." The -ing is adjectival. If our example were "Notices asking people to contact ... were placed," then that would clearly be adjectival (though terrible to read). I'm inclined to say that's the right answer.

Comment: @Lambie, it's an adverbial clause, isn't it?

Comment: "Notices |asking people to contact the filmmaker if they knew how to get hold of trained ravens| were placed in the press all over the United States."  Not sure it's a result. It's a present participle phrase describing notices.  So, adjectival. It modifies notices.

Comment: @mahmudkpukayoor It refers to "notices", and is thus predicative, but it's a depictive adjunct (your adverbial) in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ, Please post an answer with some details and more examples.